# Creating a new layout folder in android studio

Tags: android

Can someone let me know why creating a different layout folder in the android studio does not work? It allows you to create the folder but the folder does not appear afterward in the directory tree.

Comment: It gets created but is not visible if you keep the directory tree view to Android. Change the view to Project or Project Files and then check it in res folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the image for better understand for you,

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Folder is created but it is not show because of **Android view**.You need to change **Android view** to **Project view** in top left side of android studio.

[image: Screen Shot]

I hope that can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks guys, that helped. Thanks once more for the knowledge.

Comment: Most Welcome ^_^

Comment: @PaulDavies If it's work for you, So, can you give this answer as marked answer? Because of it is helpful for other people.

Comment: @PaulDavies If it's helpful so can you give this answer as marked answer?